# In the Littlewood’s 1st Principle, why do we need the finiteness assumption m∗ (E) < ∞?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

> **Theorem**  **(Littlewood's 1st Principle)**
>
> Every measurable set of finite measure is nearly a finite union of disjoint open intervals, in the sense
>
> (i) If E is measurable and **m∗(E) < ∞**, then for any ε > 0 there is a finite union U
>   of open intervals such that m∗(U△E) < ε.(Clearly, the intervals can be chosen
>   to be disjoint.)
>
> (ii) If for any ε > 0 there is a finite union U of open intervals such that m∗
>   (U△E) <
>   ε, then E is measurable.(The finiteness assumption m∗
>   (E) < ∞ is not essential.)

I don't understand why this theorem need the assumption m∗ (E) < ∞.

Will there be a counter example if the assumption is changed to **m∗ (E) = ∞** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $E = [1,2] \cup [3,4] \cup [5,6] \cup \cdots$

Comment: I'll check it. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: I tried to confirm, but I am not sure why this is a counterexample. May I ask for a little more advice?

Comment: @user81787: Let $U$ be a finite union of open intervals $I_1, \dots, I_n$.  Consider four cases: (1) all the $I_k$ are bounded intervals; (2) at least one $I_k$ is of the form $(-\infty, b)$; (3) at least one $I_k$ is of the form $(a, +\infty)$; (4) at least one of the $I_k$ is $\mathbb{R}$.  Show that in each case, $m^*(U \Delta E) = \infty$.  (Note that here I'm assuming that you allow "open intervals" to be unbounded, i.e. they can be half-lines or all of $\mathbb{R}$.  If not then you only have to consider case 1.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I hope you are happy today :)